# Time to read student evals again (shudder)

Tags: teaching, course-evaluation

Why do the negative ones hurt so much more than the positive ones feel good?  Should I even read them this time?  If so, please give me the courage.

Comment: It's not a unique concern, but I don't think this is really a question.

Comment: I will send you a package of courage per mail.

Answer (score 10):

Because, as every other desirable thing, Joy is a concave function:

[image]

Comment: Stack Exchange is in good mood today:)

Comment: @Haque Graph your sorrows, so that they don't become graphic.